# TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: 5c6a2800-2077-497d-913d-5fbc0cf5e4a2

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019

I started getting this error this morning. It occurs anytime I try to check in files or perform actions like Show History.

Any idea how I can resolve it?

I'm connecting to an on premise TFS server via http.

Comment: Hi Matt, do you encounter any issue when perform actions about source control via web portal? Or clone the repo via command-line? You can try repairing or updating VS to latest version to check if it helps.

Comment: I've just upgraded to v16.9.5 and now every time I try to check in, i get a "Warning. No pending changes" message. There are many checked out and modified files..

Comment: Yes, I can successfully make changes and check in using the web portal

Comment: In other solutions i'm still getting the Internal Error Occurred message

Comment: It doesn't look like issue of TFS server since you can check in it using web portal.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing the issue by creating a new workspace and my changes across to there.
No idea what the problem was..